# Inserto into table select * from - web2py DAL

Tags: web2py, database-abstraction

Ciao,

I need to execute a query like

```
insert into TableA Select * form TableB
```

where tableA and TableB share the same structure. How can I accomplish this result using the web2py DAL (in order to abstract the query from the database specific syntax)?

I add also that TableB has about million rows and 20 columns.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The web2py DAL does not have an API for generating such a query, so you will have to use raw SQL. You can still use the DAL connection by using its `.executesql` method:

```
db.executesql('insert into TableA select * from TableB')
```